# Survival estimation goes crazy when I move all censored times to t=0

Tags: estimation, survival, censoring

I have a simulated dataset with 1000 observations and Weibull-distributed survival time as outcome. A certain percentage $p_1$ of these guys belong to a risk group ($Z_i=1$ for risk group, $Z_i=0$ for non-risk group). I'm estimating this $p_1$ with an EM algorithm and everything works nicely.

Now if I add 1000 non-informative persons to the data set of 1000 existing persons, the algorithm goes crazy and converges to $p_1=1$. My noninformative observations are all censored at t=1, i.e. an age of 1 year. (I'd like to lower this to t=0 eventually, but am trying to avoid things like a hidden $\log(0)$ somewhere in my code for now)

Is there a reasonable explanation why the adding of 1000 persons with zero information, i.e. very early censoring, would influence the estimation process at all?

Comment: What kind of model are you estimating with the EM? By the algorithm goes crazy, does it mean that it does not converge? Did you program the EM yourself? Does this happen for all the simulated data sets, or only for some? BTW, it's good practice in an EM algorithm to return some error if the likelihood does not increase at every step, as a basic check.

Comment: The model: I assume the Weibull parameters as given and am only estimating $p_1$ as well as a factor $\alpha$ by which the hazard rate is increased in the risk group (i.e. $Z_i=1$).
The EM goes crazy, because it converges to $p_1=1$, which does not happen when I leave the censored data as-is.
I did program it myself, but at this point am fairly certain that everything is correct, since it works well with "correct" data. I compared the likelihood trace to the result of an optimization of the marginal likelihood, and it's exactly the same.
It happens to all data sets I've looked at so far.

Comment: If you trust that the EM indeed converges there, it might be that this is a local maxima instead of the global maxima (but this is unlikely in my experience). If you also think it converges to the correct MLE, then this should be explained by the way your model works. I am not sure that censored observations do not contain any information; especially considering that you are adding as many as the original observations.